# Left and right functions not working in my VBA code, expecting array?

Tags: vba, excel

When I run this code through Excel, it says the Left(,) function is expecting an array. I'm passing it a `String`, the function requires a `String`, the variable is declared as a `String`. I put the `$` operator on there and it still gives me crap. Any idea what might be going on?

FWIW this executes just fine when I run it through SolidWorks.

Also, it's being called from a userform that passes it a `String`.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal _
    pszPath As String) As Long

    Declare PtrSafe Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) _
    As Long

#Else
    Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal _
    pszPath As String) As Long

    Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) _
    As Long
#End If
Public Type BROWSEINFO
#If VBA7 Then
    hOwner As LongPtr
    pidlRoot As LongPtr
    pszDisplayName As String
    lpszTitle As String
    ulFlags As Long
    lpfn As LongPtr
    lParam As LongPtr
    iImage As Long

#Else
    hOwner As Long
    pidlRoot As Long
    pszDisplayName As String
    lpszTitle As String
    ulFlags As Long
    lpfn As Long
    lParam As Long
    iImage As Long
#End If
End Type

Private bInfo As BROWSEINFO
Function GetDirectory(Optional Msg As String = "Select a folder.") As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim x As Long, pos As Integer
    'dim
    bInfo.pidlRoot = 0&     '   Root folder = Desktop
    bInfo.lpszTitle = Msg   '   Dialog title
    bInfo.ulFlags = &H1     '   Type of directory to return


    x = SHBrowseForFolder(bInfo)

    path = Space$(512)
    If SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal x, ByVal path) Then
        pos = InStr(path, Chr$(0))
        GetDirectory = Left(path, (pos - 1))
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I built a macro VBA 7.-0. Tested your code, worked fine from a new form with one button. Line of code: MsgBox GetDirectory("yes")

Comment: @Jerez This is an imported module I got from a Solidworks macro I've cobbled together after days of googling. Do you think it would fix my problem if I just copied and pasted the code instead of using the imported modules?

Comment: What is the name of the Imported Module?

Comment: @SiddharthRout It's called GetDirectoryAPI, it's part of [this](http://sw.fcsuper.com/index.php?name=UpDownload&req=getit&lid=101) macro for SolidWorks. Solidworks runs it just fine, I'm just trying to run it from excel from an external design table. Eventually this will be part of a larger project to create tons of parts from an existing database, but for now I'm just trying to cure my string slicing blues.

Comment: @Jerez I built a test and ran the same line of code as you, got the same error I've been getting. Highlights the `GetDirectory` function in yellow, then highlights the `left` function as if I were going to copy and paste it, with the error "Compile Error Expected Array" dialog box.

Comment: May I see your workbook?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I fixed the problem by calling the function directly, i.e. `VBA.Left()` rather than just `Left()`, so I guess there was a conflict with some of the reference libraries I pulled in.

Answer (score 0):

pls try the below code , it works

```
Option Explicit

 '32-bit API declarations
Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal _
pszpath As String) As Long

Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BrowseInfo) _
As Long

Public Type BrowseInfo
    hOwner As Long
    pIDLRoot As Long
    pszDisplayName As String
    lpszTitle As String
    ulFlags As Long
    lpfn As Long
    lParam As Long
    iImage As Long
End Type

Function GetDirectory(Optional msg) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim bInfo As BrowseInfo
    Dim path As String
    Dim r As Long, x As Long, pos As Integer

     'Root folder = Desktop
    bInfo.pIDLRoot = 0&

     'Title in the dialog
    If IsMissing(msg) Then
        bInfo.lpszTitle = "Please select the folder of the excel files to copy."
    Else
        bInfo.lpszTitle = msg
    End If

     'Type of directory to return
    bInfo.ulFlags = &H1

     'Display the dialog
    x = SHBrowseForFolder(bInfo)

     'Parse the result
    path = Space$(512)
    r = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal x, ByVal path)
    If r Then
        pos = InStr(path, Chr$(0))
        GetDirectory = Left(path, pos - 1)
    Else
        GetDirectory = ""
    End If
End Function

Sub CombineFiles()
    Dim path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim LastCell        As Range
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim WS              As Worksheet
    Dim ThisWB          As String

    ThisWB = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    path = GetDirectory
    FileName = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        If FileName <> ThisWB Then
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=path & "\" & FileName)
            For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
                Set LastCell = WS.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
                If LastCell.Value = "" And LastCell.Address = Range("$A$1").Address Then
                Else
                    WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                End If
            Next WS
            Wkb.Close False
        End If
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set Wkb = Nothing
    Set LastCell = Nothing
End Sub
```